# Error.code 1 on upload images on iOS using Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I have tried every trick in the book to upload images to server using `FileTransfer` but nothing seems to work.

I have no issue uploading using `Android`, the only issue is with `iOS`. No matter what I did I keep receiving error code 1.

Here is what I did, first I added the plugins so when I check using CLI `phonegap local plugin list` I get this:

```
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.camera
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.file
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.media
```

In my code I use this:

```
<button onclick='capturePhoto();' type='button'>Take Picture</button>
<img src='' id='smallImageConfirm' />
<script>
var sendAttachment;
function capturePhoto() {
    $.mobile.loading( "show", { text: "Loading", textVisible: "visible", theme: "a"});
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 30, correctOrientation: true, targetWidth: 320, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

    // Get image handle
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImageConfirm');

    // Unhide image elements
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';

    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    sendAttachment = imageData;

    $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
            uploadToServer();
}


function uploadToServer() {

    $.mobile.loading( "show", { text: "Uploading", textVisible: "visible", theme: "a"});
    $("#submit_button").attr('disabled', true);
    var url = encodeURI("http://www.xxx.com/handler.php");

    var params = new Object();
    params.userName = "admin;
    params.randName = "xxxxzzzzaaaa123";

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file"; //depends on the api
    options.fileName = sendAttachment.substr(sendAttachment.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = true; //this is important to send both data and files

    alert( sendAttachment.substr(sendAttachment.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) );
    alert( sendAttachment );

            //tried without these too and didn't work
    sendAttachment = sendAttachment.replace("file:///", "");
    sendAttachment = sendAttachment.replace("file://", "");
    alert( sendAttachment );

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(sendAttachment, url, 
                function win(r) {alert(r.response);}, 
                function fail(error){alert(error.code + "  " + error.source + "  " + error.target);}, 
            options);
    $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
}
</script>
```

As said on `iOS` only I get `error.code=1` and `error.source` something like `localhost/var/mobile/Applications/0988888888332/tmp/cdv_photo_001.jpg` and `error.target` the `var = url` above

Please help